# Running external programs in a sandboxed app

Tags: objective-c, macos

How can I make an app to show all users logged in to the computer using the w command in terminal?

I made the beta app but it's working sandboxing disabled [it shows the users]but it's not working with sandboxing enabled[it sais that there are no users logged in]. The code is :

```
NSTask *task = [NSTask new];
[task setLaunchPath:@"/usr/bin/w"];

NSPipe *output = [NSPipe pipe];
[task setStandardInput:[NSPipe pipe]];
[task setStandardOutput: output];

[task launch];
NSFileHandle * read = [output fileHandleForReading];
NSData * dataRead = [read readDataToEndOfFile];
NSString *result = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataRead encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
[TView setString: result];
```

Answer (score 0):

The utility that you're trying to run (`w`) is attempting to access a file that is outside the sandbox. In short, it will not work when launched from a sandboxed application.

Comment: is there any other method to see the logged users which can be used with sandbox ?

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the [source](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/cvsweb.cgi/src/usr.bin/w/) from the FreeBSD `w` command to implement its functionality *inside* your app and seeing if that works (no idea if it will or not).  But at least you won't have issues with running external programs...

However if it needs access to non-standard areas then it won't work in a sandboxed app.